# If the function $f(x)=(x^2+ax+b)\lfloor x \rfloor$ is continuous in range of (1,4) , then how do I find $a$ and $b$?

Tags: limits

If $$f(x)=(x^2+ax+b)\lfloor x \rfloor$$
And this function has "CONTINUITY" in this range $$(1,4)$$
So now how to find:

1. $a=?$
2. $b=?$

Sorrily I don't really know how to do within this hard question. I want to do some with it , but I couldn't. Please help!

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is discontinuous in $\{2,3\}$. To avoid these discontinuities, make null the polynomial in these points.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that continuity anyway holds at non-integer points, because here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is continuous(why?) and $x^2+ax+b$ is continuous anyway, so $f$ being the product of these will be continuous.

The only problematic points will then be $2$ and $3$ which lie in the domain. For example, for continuity at $2$ you just need to find what $a$ and $b$ satisfy $\lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) = f(2)$.

But note that $\lim_{x \to 2^+} f= 2(2^2+2a+b)$ and $\lim_{x \to 2^-} f = 3(2^2+2a+b)$. Therefore, you get $4+2a+b = 0$ by equating these.

Similarly, doing this for $3$ gives $9+3a+b = 0$. Now you have two simultaneous equations in two variables.